# Python API: C Extension install error

Tags: python, c, api

I'm using Mac, and I am trying to write my own c code to use it from Python. I'm new to this, and trying out a sample example from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions.htm.

But, when I run the setup.py file to install my c file, it gives me an error, and I'm not sure what to do. Below is the resulting error message. Thanks a lot!

```
$ sudo python3 setup.py install

Password:
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'sample' extension
clang -Wno-unused-result -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DFOO=1 -UBAR -I/some/dir -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -c pysample.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4/pysample.o
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4/pysample.o -L/usr/local/lib -lsample -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4/sample.so
ld: library not found for -lsample
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: `library not found for -lsample` this is the problem here, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Sourav, I've changed that part of the code which removed the error